# Отключить домен или запретить индексацию через robots.txt?

Tags: seo

Такая ситуация: зарегистрировали новый домен. Некоторое время он был закрыт от индексации, так как там висела только дефолтная страница от хостинга, типа сайт только что создан, контент скоро появится.

Через некоторое время загрузили туда CMS, заказали материал и наполнили им сайт, убрали в robots.txt код который запрещает индексацию сайта поисковикам(разрешили индексировать).

В итоге оказалось что предоставленный от исполнителя материал(текста) - почти полная копия(плагиат) с других сайтов схожей тематики.

Текста (плагиат) висели на нашем сайте чуть больше недели. В гугле сайт еще числиться как зарытый от индексации:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В яндексе сайт вообще не находит еще, даже если просто в запрос ввести домен, хотя в яндекс.вебмастер уже зарегистрирован домен около недели.

Вопрос такой: Что лучше сделать, отключить домен (чтобы при переходе на него отвечало *Не удается получить доступ к сайту* либо же закрыть его от индексации через robots.txt ?

Так как еще примерно две недели будут подготавливаться новые материалы для сайта, сейчас там просто шаблон с битыми ссылками на пустые страницы.

Что лучше с точки зрения seo?

Answer (score 0):

1 вариант, поскольку "Инструкции robots.txt носят рекомендательный характер".

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=ru